# Symmetries group of hexagon

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, dihedral-groups

i'm trying to understand how to build a group H that contains complex functions and its operation is function composition. 
I really don´t undestand how to build that group for a hexagon in the complex plane, however I found the matrix 2 by 2 representation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (there are 12 matrixes and I found them). 
So, the question is:

> Determine the group of symmetries of the hexagon as a group H of complex functions $\in \mathbb{C}$
>
> Write out the multiplication table of H

I need 12 functions ( I think ) because I need to make a Cayley table and then compare with matrixes Caley table.
I hope you can help me, *thanks*.

Comment: Identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the dihedral group with 12 elements. Its group table can be found [here].

Let $\omega:=e^{i\pi/3}$, a primive $6$-th root of unity.

The group of isometries of hexagon

$$1,\omega, \ \omega^2, \ \omega^3, \ \omega^4, \ \omega^5 $$

can be generated by the two complex functions

$$f_1(z)=\omega z \ \ \text{and} \ \ f_2(z)=\bar z$$

(conjugate of $z$)

by combining $f_2$ (rotation by $\pi/3$) and $f_3$ (symmetry with respect to $x$-axis), you generate all transformations keeping the hexagon invariant.

Edit :

Here are some of the constituents of this group, where $c=\cos(\pi/3)$ and $s=\sin(\pi/3)$ :

$$\begin{matrix}f_1(z)=z & \leftrightarrow & \binom{1 \ 0}{0 \ 1} \\
f_2(z)=\omega z & \leftrightarrow & \binom{c \ -s}{s \ \ \ \ c} \\
f_3(z)=\bar z & \leftrightarrow & \binom{0 \ 1}{1 \ 0} \\
f_4(z)=f_2(f_3(z))=\omega \bar z & \leftrightarrow & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \binom{c \ -s}{s \ 
 \ \ \ c}\binom{0 \ 1}{1 \  0}=...\\
f_5(z)=f_2(f_2(z))=\omega^2 z  & \leftrightarrow & \binom{-c \ -s}{s \ \ \ -c}\\
... &...&...\end{matrix}$$

Comment: I need to find twelve "maps", so they give me an example with dihedrical group  and H group is conformed by 8 elements. I require this, because I need to compare these with 2 by 2 matrixes and determine if there is an isomorphism

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: Sincerely, i didn't understand how to "combine" that two functions to generate all the group :(